# Why silver reflectivity decreases at around 350

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, reflection, orbitals, metals, absorption

[image]

This picture is from the site:https://www.zmescience.com/other/feature-post/gold-color-relativity/

I was wondering why the reflectivitiy of silver goes to 0 at around 350 nm. I understand why for gold and silver the reflectivity increases with wavelength(because the energy gap between the d and s orbitals are high) but why the dip at 350 nm? Thank you.

Comment: Plasma frequency…

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how plasma frequency reduces the reflectance @JonCuster?

Comment: https://unlcms.unl.edu/cas/physics/tsymbal/teaching/SSP-927/Section%2013_Optical_Properties_of_Solids.pdf to start.

Comment: The link you sent was a bit too technical for me but I did some other reading and I think I have a rough ide of how plasma frequency makes silver less reflective.

Comment: From what I understand, at low plasma frequencies(which are a measure for how fast electrons move), the electrons interact with the electric field part of light to emit another light that overpowers the first light, so reflecting the light.  However, at high plasma frequencies, the electrons are too fast and don't interact with electric field enough to emit light and they let the light pass through.  In the case of silver, there is something about the orbitals that prevents it from going into lower plasma frequencies for around 350 nm like other metals. So it's reflectance goes down.

Comment: @JonCuster is this correct?